# Seeing the source code instead of a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, mamp

I'm kind of new in ASP.NET and C# so it may sound a stupid question.
I installed MAMP in order to have a testing server.
My project is in the htdocs directory.

I'm working with mac and as I said I'm trying to learn C# and ASP.NET.
When I try to preview my website in dreamweaver, I see the source code instead of the website (when not in "live view" I see the example button I put in the code).

When I use mono-develop, the same project works good on the browser. I think the problem is with MAMP or apache but I'm not sure...

Comment: You need to add mod_mono to your apache server. Check this: http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAMP is specifically for Apache, MySQL and PHP installations.  ASP and C# are Microsoft languages and the MAMP server will not recognize them.  You need Windows to have a c# server. I tried to do what you are doing: get Windows 7, it is easier.

Luckily:

1. You can run Windows on your Mac
2. Microsoft gives out [free developer tools](http://www.microsoft.com/express) including [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express)  which will help you get started.

Alternatively you can get a .NET web host for less than $7 per month and try all of your creations out on their server.  It would still be a challenge for a beginner to code on a Mac and pull it off though.

Comment: Sounds logic but strange:
The source code appears on the screen when I try to preview the website from dreamweaver (using google chrome).
When I copy and paste the same code to mono-develop, it opens it in google chrome as well but this time I can see the website itself and the sample button is working as well...